# Issues running a simple example using operator overloading

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, operator-overloading

I am trying to test some examples using operator overloading but am coming across some problems. I figured these problems were pretty prevalent and found many answers that were helpful, but I still cannot get this simple code to run.

I am on mac using vscode and tried using g++ and linking the files as well but the same error occurs.

```
// test.h file
#include <iostream>

class test {

public: 
int num;
test();
test(int);
test operator+ (test);

friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, test);

friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, test);

};


// test.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

test ::test(){

}

test::test(int a){
    num = a;
}

test test :: operator+ (test ao){

    test brandnew;
    brandnew.num = num + ao.num;

    return brandnew;
}

int main(){

    test a(25);
    test b(25);
    test c;

    c = a +b;

    std::cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting to get a result of 50 in my output. Here is the error:
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
          "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, test)", referenced from:
          _main in test-823d00.o
        ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to     see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple, while you **declared**

```cpp
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, test);
```

You never actually **defined** an implementation. You probably just want to say

```cpp
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, test t) {
  out << t.num;
  return out;
}
```

Comment: @henri-menke Thanks, I'd forget the return in real life too :D

Comment: ahhh, thanks I appreciate it! Now I understand what "Undefined symbols" mean